# Why my img hover not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change my next && prev img when on.hover.

I had tried using JS but it does not seem to work.

PS: I tried different method for Prev and Next

HTML

```html
<div align='center'>
  <a href='#'>
    <img class='img-responsive pull-left'  
         src='images/arrow_left.jpg' 
         onmouseover='hover(this);' 
         onmouseout='unhover(this);'> </a>
  <ul class='pagination'>
    <li><a href='#'> 1 </a></li>
    <li><a href='#'> 2 </a></li>
    <li><a href='#'> 3 </a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>view all</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href='#'>
    <img class='img-responsive pull-right' 
         src='images/arrow_right.jpg'  onmouseover='this.src='images/arrow_rightover.jpg'
                                                                                         onmouseout='this.src='images/arrow_right.jpg'> </a>
</div>
```

JS function

```
function hover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'images/arrow_leftover.jpg');
}

function unhover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'images/arrow_left.jpg');
}
```

Comment: The onmouseover and onmouseout have multiple single apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
onmouseover='this.src='images/arrow_rightover.jpg' onmouseout='this.src='images/arrow_right.jpg'>
```

To:

```
onmouseover='this.src="images/arrow_rightover.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="images/arrow_right.jpg"'>
```

Because the browser "think" that the attribute's value is only `this.src=`

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I did tried what u mention above, but i will received error message as I created the page using php `echo""`. If i change`' '` to `" "`, i will receive this. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'images' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Ah ha. Thanks again for the respond. Problem solved. I change the code to `onmouseover='this.src=\"images/arrow_rightover.jpg\"' onmouseout='this.src=\"images/arrow_right.jpg\"'`

Answer (score 1):

wrong quotes

```
  <a href='#'>
    <img class='img-responsive pull-right' 
         src='images/arrow_right.jpg'  
         onmouseover='this.src= "images/arrow_rightover.jpg"'
         onmouseout= 'this.src="images/arrow_right.jpg"'>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function hover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'images/arrow_leftover.jpg');
}

function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'images/arrow_left.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div align='center'>
  <a href='#'>
    <img class='img-responsive pull-left' src='images/arrow_left.jpg' onmouseover='hover(this);' onmouseout='unhover(this);'>
  </a>
  <ul class='pagination'>
    <li><a href='#'> 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'> 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'> 3 </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>view all</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href='#'>
    <img class='img-responsive pull-right' src='images/arrow_right.jpg' onmouseover='this.src="images/arrow_rightover.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="images/arrow_right.jpg"'>
  </a>
</div>
```